# Italics Usage in Dictionaries

Tags: dictionaries, italics

I've only recently realized that the example sentences in many English dictionaries are italicized. And I've yet to find out any other medium that uses italics in examples.

What is the history of using italics in example sentences? Did dictionaries pioneer the usage of italics in examples or were there other forms of publications before them?

Comment: It's just a simple way to distinguish the examples from the definitions.